# Eclipse CDT plugin problems

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt, msys

im trying to run a c program on my windows 7 computer using eclipse and im running into a little snag. I currently have Eclipse downloaded on my computer with the CDT plugin and i have also downloaded Mingw and set it to my path. When i build my simple "Hello world" program it does create a debug file with the makefile and everything in it but the concle dialog states

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project C_Test ****

make all
```

> `Cannot run program "make" (in directory "C:\Users\Chmoder\workspace\C_Test\Debug"):  CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   Error: Program "make" is not found in PATH
>
> PATH=[C:\Users\Chmoder\Downloads\eclipse;C:\MINGW\Bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Stream\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Stream\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared]`

Also, when i try to run my program after building it, it says
"Binary not found"

any help people?

Comment: Did you download and install a "msys" ? `Make`  utility is not part of mingw, but part of related msys.

Comment: Rename your `mingw32-make.exe` to `make.exe` .

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to set the MINGW_HOME variable in eclipse.ini :

```
-DMINGW_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW
```

This avoid to change the system PATH (often requires administrator rights)

(solution suggested by [help of eclipse / CDT](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm&cp=11_0))

Answer (score 4):

The error is: there is no `make` in %PATH. Make is UNIX utility to help building a projects. For windows OS, the `make` utility is part of msys, not of mingw32.

According to your path and to my setup of mingw and msys, you have no msys installed (or the path of Msys was not recorded in system %PATH variable).

For you, msys will be like this path in $PATH variable:

```
  C:\MINGW\msys\1.0\Bin;
```

Msys can be downloaded from http://www.mingw.org/ too.

If you did a download of universal installer (it is the easiest variant), you just should check, is there a `make.exe` file in the `C:\MINGW\msys\1.0\Bin` directory and add this directory to the system PATH variable.

Comment: How do fix mine if I am using Cygwin?

Comment: Find a make utility in cygwin installation directory and add folder with make to PATH

Answer (score 0):

For me (on OS X), even though my personal environment (i.e. if in bash, echo $PATH) had /Developer/usr/bin in it, I still had to add it to Eclipse's Environment variables:

Go to Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Environment -> Add.. -> "${PATH}:/Developer/usr/bin

In the case of cygwin, you'd just put the right directory to where `make` is.

This was confusing for me, so figured share the details that helped me. :)

source: [eclipse forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/773854/) via [Adel on another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579135/program-make-not-found-in-path#comment15319822_11579135).

Answer (score 0):

- Goto "Window"->"Prefenerces"->"C++"->"Build"->"Environment"
- add "COMMAND"="c:\mingw\bin\make.exe"`.
- on the other side, you need a batch file `"c:\mingw\bin\rm.bat"`
- In that file, put:

  ```
  @echo off
  :start
      if "%1" == "" goto end
      if "%1" == "-f" goto loop
      del %1
  :loop
      shift
      goto start
  :end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse Luna version.

I could not even compile the "Hello World" example that comes embedded in the IDE. It kept saying that make file was not found in the path even though it was.

I tried every suggestion in this forum (making sure the path was in Windows and Eclipse variables, and making the rm.bat file) but nothing helped.

What I did is that I copied make.exe from C:\MINGW\msys\1.0\Bin and paste it into the folder where eclipse.exe resides. This might not be the optimal solution but it solved it.