# Program "make" not found in PATH

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I'm having the Program "make" not found in PATH error in eclipse. I checked the path variable which is:

```
C:\cygwin\bin;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
%ANDROID_SDK%\tools;
%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools;
%ANDROID_NDK%;
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

The `PATH` starts with the folder which contains make (I checked and `make.exe` is in there), but eclipse still goes `Program "make" not found in PATH`.

I have tried changing the path and restarting several times but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Do you have a `make.exe` file somewhere in your path, e.g. in `C:\cygwin\bin` ? You should install GNU make otherwise.

Comment: @AdelBoutros There's no prohibition against asking the same question at different places on the Internet. It's a big place. Don't chastise people for asking for help.

Answer (score 59):

You may try altering toolchain in case if for some reason you can't use gcc. Open **Properties** for your project (by right clicking on your project name in the **Project Explorer**), then **C/C++ Build** > **Tool Chain Editor**. You can change the current builder there from *GNU Make Builder* to *CDT Internal Builder* or whatever compatible you have.

Comment: This finally worked for me after I installed MinGW's gcc / g++ compiler-drivers and got MinGW's *bin* folder into my Windows path.

Comment: My path is "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\ProgramFiles\MinGW\bin;D:\ProgramFiles\runtime\win64;D:\ProgramFiles\bin;D:\ProgramFiles\polyspace\bin;". I have installed MinGW and added "D:\ProgramFiles\MinGW\bin;" in the path. But it doesn't help.

Comment: You sir, deserve a promotion.

Answer (score 23):

Are you trying to run "Hello world" for the first time? Please make sure you choose proper toolchain. For Windows you have to choose MinGW GCC.
[image]

To make MinGW GCC compiler as default or change you original project with error "Program “make” not found in PATH" or "launch failed binary not found eclipse c++" when you trying to run program simply go to
Windows >> Preferences >> C\C++ Build >> Tool Chain Editor >> Change Current toolchain to MinGW GCC

[image]

Answer (score 18):

In MinGW, I had to install the following things:

```
Basic Setup -> mingw32-base  
Basic Setup -> mingw32-gcc-g++  
Basic Setup -> msys-base
```

And in Eclipse, go to

```
Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment
```

And set the following environment variables (with "Append variables to native environment" option set):

```
MINGW_HOME   C:\MinGW
PATH   C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

Click "Apply" and then "OK".

This worked for me, as far as I can tell.

Comment: for me your stuff gave me the solution

Comment: Yeah, for me too

Answer (score 12):

If you are using MinGw, rename the mingw32-make.exe to make.exe in the folder " C:\MinGW\bin " or wherever minGw is installed in your system.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify the details that Adel's linked eclipse forum covers, here's how I solved this (on OS X):

Note: for me, even though my personal environment (i.e. if in bash, echo $PATH) had /Developer/usr/bin in it, I still had to add it to Eclipse's Environment variables:

Go to `Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment -> Add.. -> "${PATH}:/Developer/usr/bin"`

In the case of some other OS, just use the right path where make exists.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MinGW toolchain for CDT, make.exe is found at C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

(or search the make.exe in MinGW folder.)

Add this path in eclipse
window->preferences->environment

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed 'make' tool through Cygwin's installer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU MCU Eclipse on Windows, make sure [Windows Build Tools](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/windows-build-tools/install/) are installed, then check the installation path and fill the "Global Build Tools Path" inside Eclipse Window/Preferences... :

[image: Global Build Tools Path]

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are some files inside `C:\cygwin\bin called xxxxxmake.exe`, try renaming it to `make.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
  Initially I had setup Eclipse CDT with Cygwing & was working smoothly. One day there happened a problem due to which I had to reset windows. After that when I opened Eclipse I started facing the issue described above. This is how I solved it.

First I searched that in the error the PATH variable value is same as the PATH variable of windows ( just by manual comparison of both two values ). I found that to be same. Now I realized that it is a PATH problem.

Then started looking for Cygwin whether it is there or not? It was there. I located & found that it exists in

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>
C:\cygwin64\bin>dir ma*
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 042E-11B5

 Directory of C:\cygwin64\bin

16-05-2015  18:34            10,259 mag.exe
13-08-2013  04:57               384 mailmail
11-04-2015  02:56             4,252 make-emacs-shortcut
15-02-2015  23:25           194,579 make.exe
04-05-2015  21:36            40,979 makeconv.exe
29-07-2013  11:57            29,203 makedepend.exe
16-05-2015  18:34            79,891 makeindex.exe
16-05-2015  18:34            34,323 makejvf.exe
07-05-2015  03:04               310 mako-render
18-04-2015  02:07            92,179 man.exe
18-04-2015  02:07           113,683 mandb.exe
13-08-2013  04:57               286 manhole
18-04-2015  02:07            29,203 manpath.exe
24-10-2014  13:31           274,461 mate-terminal.exe
24-10-2014  13:31             1,366 mate-terminal.wrapper
              15 File(s)        905,358 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  373,012,271,104 bytes free

C:\cygwin64\bin>
```

Then I simply went ahead & updated the PATH variable to include this path & restarted eclipse.

The code compiles & debugging (GDB ) is working nicely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project> Properties> C/C++ Build>** Environment. You will see three fields, choose PATH. See if the folder containing make.exe is appended to the path or not. Sometimes the change to the System PATH variable (made from My Computer> Properties> Advanced System Settings...) is NOT reflected in Eclipse. This solved the problem for me, hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

Additional hint: If you have multiple projects with different toolchains open, check the build console header for the failing project's path.

I've just spent half an hour trying to fix a build that showed this error because another project with hopelessly outdated toolchain settings was open in the same workbench. Closing the other project re-enabled the build.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem but solved it by installing QT and extract the omnet5.6 folder in C: