# Error: Program "make" not found in PATH in QNX Momentics

Tags: c++, eclipse, blackberry-10, qnx, momentics

I am developing app in bb10 native sdk. All of a sudden QNX Momentics started showing error in all my projects and display this error in the console after cleaning the projects

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\bin;C:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\sbin;C:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\sbin;C:\bbndk\features\com.qnx.tools.jre.win32_1.7.0.51\jre/bin;C:/bbndk//features/com.qnx.tools.jre.win32_1.7.0.51/jre/bin/client;C:/bbndk//features/com.qnx.tools.jre.win32_1.7.0.51/jre/bin;C:/bbndk//features/com.qnx.tools.jre.win32_1.7.0.51/jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\bbndk]

tried the solutions in the following link but didn't solve the problem.
[Program "make" not found in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579135/program-make-not-found-in-path)

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install make for windows :

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

if it's still not working, add the path to the make binary's directory in your path :

[Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Hi,Thank you.Downloaded and installed make from the first link and copy paste the make.exe file in the bbndk bin file solved the issue.