# Eclipse build errors on default hello world

Tags: c++

I opened the hello world sample for from the Eclipse photon C++ ide, and it wouldn't build. I haven't changed any of the code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQwpk.jpg)

Comment: Possible that your error is resolved here - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579135/program-make-not-found-in-path).

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you don't have MAKE command on your machine. Install the MAKE command and add it in the PATH variable as well.