# Error: Program "make" not found in PATH when I try to build C project in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am trying to build any C project using eclipse.

I installed CDT plugin and Mingw.

However I cannot build a C project because of following error.

---

```
14:29:16 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project C_Test_02 ****
make all 
Cannot run program "make": Launching failed

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Klocwork\User 9.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\PROGRA~1\ULTRAE~1;C:\utils\checkstyle;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Klocwork\User 9.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\ProgramFiles\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\PROGRA~1\ULTRAE~1;C:\utils\checkstyle]
```

---

I added C:\MinGW\bin to my environmental path.
But 'make' is not in C:\MinGW\bin. 
I think the error occurs because C:\MinGW\bin doesn't include 'make' although I followed the Eclipse FAQ to build C project.
I can find only gcc(s), automake(s), mingw32-make(s).... in C:\MinGW\bin.

Could you let me know how I can get 'make'?

**UPDATE**

I founded 'make' file. refer to comments below)
But a makefile isn't generated automatically.
Properties>C/C++ Build>Builder Settings 'Generate Makefiles Automatically' option is diabled.

Could you let me know how I can enable this option?

Comment: I found the solution in 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134304/eclipse-cdt-plugin-problems'

Comment: You mean that you still cannot enable automatic make file generation? I'n my Eclipse i just toggle the check box.

Answer (score 3):

Create a copy of the mingw32-make exe. Rename mingw32-make to make. Include the path to the executable in PATH variable. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the eclipse CDT.
To install C/C++ compiler and Eclipse follow the instructions on this link https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

If still no success follow the @Questioner's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Already Solved this problem. Please follow this page

[Program "make" not found in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579135/program-make-not-found-in-path)

> You may try altering toolchain in case if for some reason you can't
>   use gcc. Open Properties for your project (by right clicking on your
>   project name in the Project Explorer), then C/C++ Build > Tool Chain
>   Editor. You can change the current builder there from GNU Make Builder
>   to CDT Internal Builder or whatever compatible you have.