# Eclipse C/C++ does not want to run an app, outputting an Error -.-

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, compilation

Alright, hello guys. I've been using Eclipse Luna for some time now while programming in Java. Recently, due to school work, I decided to download the C/C++ for the eclipse as well. I have installed it and all went well. Then I wrote a simple programme and Eclipse will not run it.

Each time there is a pop up: Launch failed. Binary not found.
Also, Eclipse says there is the following error: Program "make"not found in PATH.

Now, I have tried everything to fix it. I'm using the MinGW. I also downloaded Msys.I added all the necesarry paths into the System enviroment variables and done the same thing in the Eclipse.
I went into the Window -- Preferences -- C/C++ -- New C/C++ project and under Binary Parsers selected the PE Windows Parser. I've tried other things as well, like adding the following line into the eclipse.ini as someone suggested:

> -DMINGW_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW

Nothing seems to be working though and I sadly cannot run even the simplest of programs. Haalp, please.

Kind regards,
George.

Comment: Try things mentioned [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11579135/program-make-not-found-in-path) or [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7134304/eclipse-cdt-plugin-problems')